# How to Create a new array each cycle of a for loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, java.util.scanner

Hello im looking at how to create a new array and store the two values obtained from the user each iteration of the for loop. Since it goes from 1-4 i want to create 4 arrays and each time it appends the values the user gives in that iteration. If it would be better to create one big array that stores all the values, please share however I would like to keep the code simple. The example below shows my code, the array part is the part im having issues with at the moment.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Arrays{

public static void main(String args[])

String array1[];
String array2[];
String array3[];
String array4[];

for (int i=1; i <5; i++) {

    System.out.println("What is track " + i);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String track = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("How many thousands of times has it been downloaded? ");
    Scanner sd = new Scanner(System.in);
    String time = sd.nextLine();
    array1[0]=track;
    array1[1]=time;

}
System.out.println(arrays1);
System.out.println(arrays2);
System.out.println(arrays3);
System.out.println(arrays4);
}
```

Comment: Create an array that contain your 4 arrays, String[4][2]

Comment: You shouldn't be using arrays to store different fields. Use a proper class.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you can show me an example

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 2-dimensional array, in this case you will have an array of size 4, where each index will hold an array of size two. You can then use the value of `i` in your `for` loop to access the outer arrays. I would also suggest using just 1 scanner, and putting it outside of your loop as there is no need to create a new scanner for every iteration of your `for` loop. You should also try to avoid hard-coding integer values into the code and use variables since these values can be subject to change at later time. If you wanted to get for example 6 sets of values from the user, you would then have to go through your code and manually change all entries of 4 as opposed to just using a variable for this and changing the variable value.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Arrays1{

  public static void main(String args[]){

    String[][] array = new String[4][2];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        System.out.println("What is track " + i + 1);
        array[i][0] = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("How many thousands of times has it been downloaded? ");
        array[i][1] = sc.nextLine();
    }

    sc.close();

    // More elegant to loop here and print these values instead of hardcoding the indices
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array[0]));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array[1]));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array[2]));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array[3]));
  }
}
```

Comment: *You should also try to avoid hard-coding integer values* how many changes will you have to do in the above code if the number changes from 4 to 6?

Comment: @forpas This was intentional to illustrate the advice using the example of 4 and the loop comment. Feel free to edit as needed if you believe a variable example would serve better

Comment: I don't need to edit your answer because you do and after each edit (there were several) it comes closer and closer to my code but still you have work to do.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Use a 2 dimensional array 
 (2) Use 1 Scanner object

```
String[][] array = new String[4][2];
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("What is track " + (i + 1));
    array[i][0] = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("How many thousands of times has it been downloaded? ");
    array[i][1] = sc.nextLine();
}
sc.close();

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    System.out.print("track" + (i + 1) + " = " + array[i][0]);
    System.out.println(", downloaded = " + array[i][1]);
}
```